# How to sort and extract data from JFrog JSON response using groovy for Jenkins pipelining

Tags: json, api, jenkins, groovy, jfrog-cli

I am using OS version of JFrog Artifactory for my CI-CD activities which run via the Jenkins pipeline. I am novice to groovy/java
The REST APIs of OS JFrog Artifactory do not support the extraction of the latest build from a repository. With Jenkins pipeline in play, I was wondering if i could extract the data from the JSON response provided by Artifactory using Jenkins native groovy support(just to avoid external service which can be run via python/Java/Shell).

I am looking to put the extracted JSON response into a Map, sort the Map in descending order and extract the first Key-Value pair which contains the latest build info. 
I end up getting "-1" as the response when I try to extract the data.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = httpRequest authentication: 'ArtifactoryAPIKey', consoleLogResponseBody: false, contentType: 'TEXT_PLAIN', httpMode: 'POST', requestBody: '''
    items.find({
    "$and": [
        {"repo": {"$match": "libs-snapshot-local"}},
        {"name": {"$match": "simple-integration*.jar"}}
            ]
     })''', url: 'http://<my-ip-and-port-info>/artifactory/api/search/aql'

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
Map jsonOutput = jsonParser.parseText(response.content)
List resultsInfo = jsonOutput['results']
print(resultInfo[0].created)

def sortedResult = resultInfo.sort( {a, b -> b["created"] <=> a["created"] } )
sortedResult.each { 
 println it
}
```

The sample JSON to be parsed:

```
    {
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "simple-integration/2.5.150",
  "name" : "simple-integration-2.5.150.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1175,
  "created" : "2019-06-23T19:51:30.367+05:30",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2019-06-23T19:51:30.364+05:30",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2019-06-23T19:51:30.368+05:30"
},{
  "repo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "simple-integration/2.5.140",
  "name" : "simple-integration-2.5.140.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1175,
  "created" : "2019-06-21T19:52:40.670+05:30",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2019-06-21T19:52:40.659+05:30",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2019-06-21T19:52:40.671+05:30"
},{
  "repo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "simple-integration/2.5.150",
  "name" : "simple-integration-2.5.160.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1175,
  "created" : "2019-06-28T19:58:04.973+05:30",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2019-06-28T19:58:04.970+05:30",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2019-06-28T19:58:04.973+05:30"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 3,
  "total" : 3
}
}






  //The output i am looking for: Latest build info with fields "created" and "name"
```

Comment: your code should work except you misspelled variable name: `resultInfo` vs `resultsInfo`

Comment: @daggett I apologise. It is a typo. I get the same error even after changing to resultsInfo

Answer (score 0):

```
def jsonOutput = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('''
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "simple-integration/2.5.150",
  "name" : "simple-integration-2.5.150.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1175,
  "created" : "2019-06-23T19:51:30.367+05:30",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2019-06-23T19:51:30.364+05:30",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2019-06-23T19:51:30.368+05:30"
},{
  "repo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "simple-integration/2.5.140",
  "name" : "simple-integration-2.5.140.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1175,
  "created" : "2019-06-21T19:52:40.670+05:30",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2019-06-21T19:52:40.659+05:30",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2019-06-21T19:52:40.671+05:30"
},{
  "repo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "simple-integration/2.5.150",
  "name" : "simple-integration-2.5.160.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1175,
  "created" : "2019-06-28T19:58:04.973+05:30",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2019-06-28T19:58:04.970+05:30",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2019-06-28T19:58:04.973+05:30"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 3,
  "total" : 3
}
}
''')

def last = jsonOutput.results.sort{a, b -> b.created <=> a.created }[0]
println last.created
println last.name
```

Comment: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such getAt method found: method java.lang.Integer[java.lang.Integer]
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetArray(SandboxInterceptor.java:479)

Comment: do you check if there are some script to approve at http://jenkins_host/scriptApproval/

Comment: the code above is runnable. check it yourself: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5070537919299584

Comment: Your solution works. And so does mine. But, the problem here is a bug of Jenkins which yields the result as "-1" 
The issue is tracked here in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44924

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with Groovy code but the Jenkins pipeline. 
This code as part of the question, and the solution provided by @daggett works charm on any Groovy IDE But, Fails when run via jenkins pipeline.

The issue URL: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44924

I hope they fix it soon. 
Thanks for your help guys.